# Which CSS property is correct for gradient "background" or "background-image"

Tags: css, gradient

Which is the correct property to use for a CSS gradient? "background" or "background-image" as displayed below. They both work in all 5 browsers (in the versions I have). I've seen multiple tutorials and some use "background" and others use "background-image" but none of them discuss why one method is better then the other.

Neither of them validate at http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

```
.gradient {
    background-color: #1a82f7;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#2F2727, endColorstr=#1a82f7);
}
```

Or This one:

```
.gradient {
    background-color: #1a82f7;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#2F2727, endColorstr=#1a82f7);
}
```

Comment: The properties are fine (gradients are specifically considered images), but none of them are valid because they all make use of prefixed functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe using `background` is any different than using `background-image`. Basically it's like `background: url('image.png');` and `background-image: url('image.png')` -- they're the same thing, it's just that `background` is a shorthand property that allows you to specify several background properties like `background-repeat`, `background-color`, and of course `background-image`.

So basically the gradient should be specified as a `background-image`, using `background` is no different, just another way of specifying it.

As for the **W3C** validator issue, I think it's because the gradient "functions" all use browser-specific prefixes. I expect that those functions won't become officially-recognizable until **HTML5** becomes official.

Hope that helped in any manner.